# How can I disable Windows from waking up from everything but the keyboard and the power button?

Tags: sleep, window, wake-up

How can I disable Windows from waking up from everything but the keyboard and the power button? That is, I don't want my windows to wake up from the mouse at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent your mouse from waking up, do this:

1. Go to Device Manager
2. Find your mouse and go to its properties.
3. Go to the Power Management tab and disable check box, "Allow this device to wake the computer".

[image]

Repeat this process for any device you wish.

Comment: The correct solution. What more can we say? Of course there are also other way the computer wakes up, without the mouse triggering it (wake on LAN for example) But this will probably answer the question for pretty much everyone.

Comment: @StaticStorm glad to help

Comment: still my blue-touth mouse makes it wake up when I move it. why?

Comment: @アレックス You might want to mark your question for unanswered if your problem is not resolved. Maybe you didn't go to the correct device in the device manager. Also check your Bluetooth devices, and make sure they are not allowed to wake your PC.

Comment: @StaticStorm, there's no option in the bluetooth devices to "wake up" windows -- it's (the checkbox) disabled completely, rather.